# linker complains about multiple definition even there are inclusion guards

Tags: c++, templates

I can't figure out why the code does not compile, even when I have the include guards to prevent repetitive compilation

The main class foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H_INCLUDED
#define FOO_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

class Foo;

template<int TDim>
struct Foo_Helper
{
    static bool Compare(const Foo& this_foo, const Foo& other_foo);
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const int& Value) : mValue(Value) {}
    virtual ~Foo() {}
    const int& Value() const {return mValue;}
    template<int TDim>
    bool Compare(const Foo& rother_foo) {return Foo_Helper<TDim>::Compare(*this, rother_foo);}
private:
    int mValue;
};

#endif

#include "foo.hpp"
```

foo.hpp to define the template specialization:

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP_INCLUDED
#define FOO_HPP_INCLUDED

template<>
bool Foo_Helper<1>::Compare(const Foo& this_foo, const Foo& other_foo)
{
    return this_foo.Value() == other_foo.Value();
}

template<>
bool Foo_Helper<2>::Compare(const Foo& this_foo, const Foo& other_foo)
{
    return this_foo.Value() == other_foo.Value();
}

#endif
```

The two source files:
src1.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

class Test1
{
public:
    bool test()
    {
        Foo f1(1);
        Foo f2(2);

        return f1.Compare<1>(f2);
    }
};
```

src2.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

class Test2
{
public:
    bool test()
    {
        Foo f1(1);
        Foo f2(2);

        return f1.Compare<2>(f2);
    }
};
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(file_list
src1.cpp
src2.cpp
)

add_library(Test SHARED ${file_list})
```

The error messsage:

```
Linking CXX shared library libTest.so
CMakeFiles/Test.dir/src2.cpp.o: In function `Foo_Helper<1>::Compare(Foo const&, Foo const&)':
/home/hbui/workspace/c++/multiple_definition_error/foo.hpp:7: multiple definition of `Foo_Helper<1>::Compare(Foo const&, Foo const&)'
CMakeFiles/Test.dir/src1.cpp.o:/home/hbui/workspace/c++/multiple_definition_error/foo.hpp:7: first defined here
CMakeFiles/Test.dir/src2.cpp.o: In function `Foo_Helper<2>::Compare(Foo const&, Foo const&)':
/home/hbui/workspace/c++/multiple_definition_error/foo.hpp:13: multiple definition of `Foo_Helper<2>::Compare(Foo const&, Foo const&)'
CMakeFiles/Test.dir/src1.cpp.o:/home/hbui/workspace/c++/multiple_definition_error/foo.hpp:13: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [multiple_definition_error/libTest.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [multiple_definition_error/CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I thought the inclusion guard has prevented the two functions in foo.hpp to be compiled. However, it looks like that each cpp file compile its own functions. In this case, how to properly define the template specialized functions?

Comment: You're confusing linking with compiling.  The header guards prevent the compiler (that's looking at a single cpp -> object conversion) from finding multiple definitions.  The linker (that takes multiple objects -> lib/exe) tries to piece all the functions together.

Comment: Yes, but what's the solution?

Comment: Aside: why do you have two specialisations of your template that have identical bodies? What happens if someone calls `Foo::Compare<3>`?

Comment: @Caleth, the Compare function in Helper can be modified to provide a default behavior, maybe to throw an error.

Comment: @kstn it *can*, but neither version *is*. Why isn't it just a free function `bool operator==(const Foo& this_foo, const Foo& other_foo);`?

Comment: @Caleth, well it can, but this is just a small example to test the compiler. The real code is more complicated and covers the thing you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header guards stop the header being included twice in the same translation unit. Your problem is that the definitions of the `Compare` specializations will be defined in two translation units, but are not marked `inline`. This means that when the linker tries to link the object files produced by test1.cpp and test2.cpp, it gives you a multiple definition error. If you mark the specializations as `inline` then they can be defined in two TUs and the linker will just throw away one of the definitions:

```
template<>
inline bool Foo_Helper<1>::Compare(const Foo& this_foo, const Foo& other_foo)
//^^^^
{
    return this_foo.Value() == other_foo.Value();
}

template<>
inline bool Foo_Helper<2>::Compare(const Foo& this_foo, const Foo& other_foo)
//^^^^
{
    return this_foo.Value() == other_foo.Value();
}
```

Comment: ah, this's cool. Now I got it. inline makes the TU to compile separately. Probably more compilation is done but it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put specialization code in .cpp. I think it may be the best solution since specialization (usually) is closely related to the newly created classes (Test1 and Test2).

Alternatively put

```
template<>
bool Foo_Helper<1>::Compare(const Foo& this_foo, const Foo& other_foo)
{
    return this_foo.Value() == other_foo.Value();
}

template<>
bool Foo_Helper<2>::Compare(const Foo& this_foo, const Foo& other_foo)
{
    return this_foo.Value() == other_foo.Value();
}
```

into foo.cpp (instead of foo.hpp) and in foo.hpp only say that specialization is "extern".

Additionally you should move class declarations from src1.cpp to src1.hpp ;)